# Can I load files as properties within a Spring Boot ConfigServer Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm looking to back my application with some properties files from a git repository. My application is annotated with @EnableConfigServer and is pulling the git repository into my directory. For some reason though none of the properties are available for use in my application. I want to use the files imported from the repository as sources for some files I have annotated with @ConfigurationProperties so I kind of want the application to be the Client and Server simultaneously.
My Git repo directory:

```
.
+-- applications
|   +-- dsfe
|   +-- on-simplicity-in-technology.markdown
|   |   +-- application.yml
|   |   +-- application-igde.yml  
|   |   +-- application-iggb.yml
```

My Server Config Properties in local application.yml:

```
spring.application.name=dsfe
spring.profiles.include=iggb,igde

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://internal.host.net/dsfe/mw-external-configuration.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=applications/dsfe
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=external-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
```

My application:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

In the yaml files I have properties files under keys "igde-dede" and would like to load them into my @ConfigurationProperties file, within the same application, like below:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "igde-dede")
public Map<String, List<SectionData>> igde_dede_SectionData() {
    return new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

but none of the properties from the git files are loaded into my application context or Environment despite the files being loaded. Am I missing anything to make the git files be included?

I've tried to use the files loaded from git in the application context but they're not included in it.

Comment: You need to show what the listing of the git repo is and the configuration of the config clients

Comment: I've added the listing of my git repo - what do you mean by configuration of the config clients?

Comment: the application.properties of the config client (anything with spring-cloud-starter-config)